# How to change the name of Ubuntu installer

Tags: 20.04, system-installation

So when you are booting Ubuntu iso there are 2 options:

1. Try Ubuntu
2. Install Ubuntu

You can press <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd>, and when you are done trying it out, there is a app called "Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" on the desktop. That brings you through the installer.

How do I change the name of that app on the desktop using Cubic?

Cubic is a tool that you can use to make Linux distros. I am making a custom distro based on Ubuntu named "zink!". In Cubic you choose the ISO you want to base the OS off of. Then it brings you to a chroot environment. In that chroot you can do terminal commands, and I want to know if using Cubic I can change it so, when you press <kbd>Try Try zink!</kbd> (my OS name), then the shortcut for the installer on the desktop of live environment is named "Install zink! 0.1" (my os name) instead of "Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS".

Does any one know how to do this?

If you do not understand what I am saying, you know how on the desktop of live USB there is a application called install "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"?...

I am making a distro using Cubic and want to know if, through Cubic, I can rename that application on desktop of live environment called "Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"?

Comment: You may want to re read your question it is not making any sense.

Comment: I edited it @David look at it now

Comment: Please provide specifics.  Ubuntu (and *flavors*) currently have four supported installers, and they are selected by ISO chosen. You haven't said if you're talking about a server installation, or desktop; both of which run different installers.  I get the feeling you're asking about the maybe-ubiquity option; but your description is vague & I'm making assumptions because of your vagueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make changes in Cubic**

This is very easy, and you do not need to do anything in Cubic's Terminal environment.

(However, there may be a small issue with the exclamation mark ("!") in your custom OS name, which I will explain below).

On the "Project" page in Cubic, in the "Custom Disk" section, rename the first part of the "Volume ID" to your custom OS name.

For example, rename...

```
Ubuntu 20.04.0 2021.04.14 LTS
```

...to...

```
zink! 20.04.0 2021.04.14 LTS
```

You will notice that the "Disk Name" automatically changes to...

```
zink! 20.04.0 2021.04.14 LTS "Custom Focal Fossa"
```

Then generate the customized ISO, as you normally would.

**Test your changes**

Boot into your new Live ISO. (You can use VirtualBox for testing).

The Ubuntu Live environment will use *everything before the first space character* of the "Disk Name" value to display these two new buttons:

1. <kbd>Try zink!</kbd>
2. <kbd>Install zink!</kbd>

Furthermore, once you have booted into the Live environment, you will see an app launcher on your Desktop for the [Ubiquity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity) installer. This app launcher will now be named "zink! 20.04.0". (This corresponds to *everything before the second space character* of the "Disk Name" value on Cubic's Project page).

**Potential issue**

Regarding, the small issue I mentioned before, when you include the exclamation mark ("!") in your OS name, the behavior of the Live Environment changes: After you click the <kbd>Try zink!</kbd> button, you will be prompted to select a locale, user name, password, and other information for the Live Environment.

As you know, the typical behavior of the Live ISO is to immediately boot you into the Live Environment as user `ubuntu`, and if you do *not* include an exclamation mark ("!") in your OS name, this is what the behavior will be.

Otherwise, with the exclamation mark ("!") in your OS name, you will need to supply this preliminary information before you can enter the Live Environment. (I think this may be a "feature" of how the Live ISO works, and you may not consider this to be a issue for you).